# Error coming while saving the news letter in my account page in magento2

Tags: magento2, newsletter, third-party-module

I am facing below issue in server. It's working fine in my local but in server not working. This error coming while saving the newsletter in My Account page, `Sign Up Newsletter` in registration page.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Config::__construct() must be of the type array, null given, called in /chroot/home/sitehtml/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 93 and defined in /chroot/home/sitehtml/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Source/Config.php:26 Stack trace: #0 /chroot/home/sitehtml/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(93): Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Config->__construct(NULL) #1 /chroot/home/sitehtml/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(88): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Eav\\Mod...', Array) #2 /chroot/home/sitehtml/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(57): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\\Eav\\Mod...', Array) #3 / in /chroot/home/sitehtml/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Source/Config.php on line 26
```

For this error I tried the `php bin/setup:di:compile` command but no use and I deleted the files in `var/generation`,`var/di`, `var/cache` and I tried the same command but still same issue coming. Please tell me any idea to fix this.

Comment: is there mailchimp extension ?

Comment: Yes I have Ebizmarts_Mailchimp. Is there any problem?

Comment: Please disable that and check is that works ?

Comment: I have faced this issue in magento 1 so

Comment: Ok i'll check and let you know dude

Comment: In helper/data.php file check my below code . It will solve your problem

Comment: This is version 1.0.26 that code not exists in helper file. I disabled the module now it's working. But why this issue occurring any idea?

Comment: Check line 315 code is there. I have modified my answer please check

Answer (score 1):

In **mailchimp extension** go to `helper/data.php` file

**find**

```
try {
                if($item->usesSource()) {
                    $options = $item->getSource()->getAllOptions();
                } else {
                    $options = [];
                }
```

**Replace with**

```
   try {
                  if($item->getFrontendInput()=='select'){
                    $options =$item->getSource()->getAllOptions();
                  }
                else{
                  $options = [];
                }
                }
                catch(\Exception $e) {

                    $options = [];
                }
```

I think it should work

Comment: @JeevaChezhiyan ok i need upvote if you found this useful